# Saving An Outlook Item from asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I have a requirement of allowing the users to save an event from an application as outlook calendar item. The code that I am using is allowing to Open the item as Outlook item. Next the user can Save&Close. On using the save prompt the item is saved as first .ics file on the system and then it needs to be reopened in outlook to save it in outlook calendar but we want direct save in outllok without being saved on the system. Please suggest.
The code used is:

```
// Define the event.
            sbICSFile.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");

            //sbICSFile.Append("DTSTART;TZID=" + "US/Eastern" + ":");
            sbICSFile.Append(StartYear);
            sbICSFile.Append(
               FormatDateTimeValue(StartMonth));
            sbICSFile.Append(
               FormatDateTimeValue(StartDay) + "T");
            sbICSFile.AppendLine("000000");

            //sbICSFile.Append("DTEND;TZID=" + "US/Eastern" + ":");
            sbICSFile.Append(EndYear);
            sbICSFile.Append(
              FormatDateTimeValue(EndMonth));
            sbICSFile.Append(
              FormatDateTimeValue(EndDay) + "T");
            sbICSFile.AppendLine("000000");

            sbICSFile.AppendLine("SUMMARY:" + Subject);
            sbICSFile.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:" + EventDetails);
            sbICSFile.AppendLine("UID:1");
            sbICSFile.AppendLine("SEQUENCE:0");

            sbICSFile.Append("DTSTAMP:" + dtNow.Year.ToString());
            sbICSFile.Append(FormatDateTimeValue(dtNow.Month));
            sbICSFile.Append(FormatDateTimeValue(dtNow.Day) + "T");
            sbICSFile.Append(FormatDateTimeValue(dtNow.Hour));
            sbICSFile.AppendLine(FormatDateTimeValue(dtNow.Minute) + "00");

            sbICSFile.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
            sbICSFile.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + Subject + "CalendarEvent.ics");
            Response.Write(sbICSFile);
            Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Send mail to attendee by attaching the .ICS file in mail attachment.